# Matlab : Read a file name in string format from a .csv file

Tags: matlab, csv

I am having a .csv file which contains let's say `50` rows.

At the beginning of each row I have a file name in the following format `001_02_03.bmp` followed by values separated by commas. Something like this :

```
001_02_03.bmp,20,30,45,10,40,20
```

Can someone tell me how can I read the first column from the data?

I know how to obtain the data from the second column onward. I am using the `csvread` function  like this `X = csvread('filename.csv', 0, 1);`. If I try to read the first column in the same manner it outputs an error, saying the `csvread` does not support string format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `textscan`, ie:

```
fid1 = fopen(csvFileName);
X = textscan(fid1, '%s%f%f%f%f%f%f', 'Delimiter', ',');
fclose(fid1);
FirstCol = X{1, 1};
```

A little more detail? `csvread` only works with purely numeric data, so you can't use it to get in data with a .bmp, or underscores for that matter. Thus we use `textscan`. The funny looking format string input to `textscan` is just saying that the columns are, in order, of type string `%s`, then the next 6 columns are of type double `%f%f%f%f%f%f` (or you might choose to alter this to reflect an integer datatype - I personally rarely bother unless the quantity of data is huge or floating point precision is a problem).

Note, if you just wanted to get the first column and ignore the rest, you can replace the format string with `%s% %*[^\n]`. A final point, if your csv file has a header line, you can skip it using the `HeaderLines` optional input to `textscan`.

Comment: @angainor That is very gracious of you, but I would have happily given you a +1 for the same answer if you posted within a minute or two of mine. Hardly seems fair that I get all the credit just because I submitted a couple of seconds ahead of you. Anyway, thanks :-)

Comment: And how can I access each individual file name from the cell?

Comment: @Simon `FirstCol` in my code above will be a cell array of size N*1, where N is the number of rows in your csv file. To access the filename of the nth row, just index into the cell array, ie `nthFileName = FirstCol{n, 1}`. Not sure how much matlab you know, but you always use curly braces `{}` to access elements of a cell array, and parentheses `()` to access elements of a numerical matrix. If you wanted to access the nth filename directly from `X`, then use `X{1, 1}{n, 1}` or even `X{1}{n}`.

Comment: @angainor A classier response I can not imagine :-)